# Average for multiple criteria in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can you help me with some formulas?

Expected result: Get the average handling time of the agent based on the criteria's met

Issue: Some of the criteria is located on the same column

Overiew:

Column A has the following data:
BH US Agent Email
BH US Chat
BH US Agent Web form

Column B has the name of the agent

Column C has the supervisor's name

Column D has the handling time per chat or email

I would like to get the combined AHT of both BH US Agent Email and BH US Agent Web form which is located in Column A

The formula I used is:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('Raw - SF'!$D:$D,'Raw - SF'! $A:$A, "Dave Cruz",'Raw - SF'!$A$2:$A$9999,"BH US Agent Email")
```

But this formula only gets the AHT of BH US Agent Email

Your help is highly appreciated guys!

Answer (score 1):

The `AVERAGEIFS` uses the following syntax:

```
average_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, criteria_range2, criteria2, etc..
```

So you just need to add one more criteria for `BH US Agent Web form`.
Full formula should look like:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('Raw - SF'!$D:$D,'Raw - SF'! $A:$A, "Dave Cruz",'Raw - SF'!$A$2:$A$9999,"BH US Agent Email",'Raw - SF'!$A$2:$A$9999,"BH US Agent Web form")
```

Comment: Hi Elvis, thanks. However, this formula is not workimg.It return a value of #DIV/0!

Comment: @DaveCruz - `AVERAGEIFS` returns a ***#DIV/0*** error when there are no values to average i.e. there is no data that satisfy all your conditions. So use `IFERROR` as `=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(....),0)`